# Android Httppost - Runtime Exception with string from edittext - Successes with static string

Tags: java, android, string, android-asynctask, http-post

I am running POST with HTTP to my php server script.

I DO succeed when i try with a static string, but i need to retrieve the data that is being input by the user..

When trying to retrieve data from the user input.

Sony Phone:
Runtime Exception

In eclipse:

```
Fatal Exception: AsycnTask #1 - java.lang.RunTimeException : An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsynkTask$3.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
```

Class Main:

```
case R.id.imageButtonServer:
    {
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvUserServerResponse);
        new HttpPostDemo().execute(textView);
        break;
    }
```

Class HttpPostDemo:

```
   public class HttpPostDemo extends AsyncTask<TextView, Void, String> 
{
    TextView textView;

    //Only present when trying to retrieve text from editText2 field//
    EditText editText2;


@Override
protected String doInBackground(TextView... params)     
{

    this.textView = params[0];
    BufferedReader inBuffer = null;
    String url = "http://myserver.com/android_java.php";
    String result = "fail";

            //This fails//
    String mail = editText2.getText().toString();

            //This runs//
    String mail = 'mail';

    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("operanda", "5"));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("operandb", "6"));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("answer", "11"));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mail", mail));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
```

main.xml :

```
      <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Email Address"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public class HttpPostDemo extends AsyncTask<TextView, Void, String> 
{
    TextView textView;

    //Only present when trying to retrieve text from editText2 field//
    EditText editText2; <- declared but not initialized
```

---

Because you did'nt initialized `editText2;`

So when performing `editText2.getText().toString();` it throws a `NullPointerException`.

I suppose you have retrieved your `editText2` in the main activity. Then just pass it as a parameter in the execute method :

```
case R.id.imageButtonServer:
    {
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvUserServerResponse);
        new HttpPostDemo().execute(textView, editText2);
        break;
    }
```

and in the `doInBackground` add the line :

```
this.editText2 = params[1];
```

Comment: @Niels Depends on where you inflate the layout to get this editText. Is it done in the same activity where you perform your switch statement ?

Comment: editText2 is input from the main.xml/main class where the post class is called from.

Comment: Tested on my device and working. Thanks a lot! A lot more understanding of java just went into my head :-)